# No internet connection in an unorthodox situation

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

Couple of years ago, I somehow created the two-router connection at my home. It was necessary since no matter of the main router's position, there's no way it could cover the whole flat. That's why I bought another router to make him communicate with the main one.
If so, models for the main is DLINK-DIR 853 and the transmitter is ZyXEL Keenetic Extra.

Recently I needed to make a refurbishment at one of my room, that's why I moved my PC to another room and tried to connect it with cord (Ethernet) as it's done with my laptop. The laptop worked fine with the cord, but PC is my main machine, and it was refusing to connect. Then I tried to get access to the main router administration panel. Well, I forgot the password, that's why I needed to reset the main router to its factory settings.

Actually, I never found what exactly it was necessary to do in that administrative panel, but anyway the situation is clear for now:

I've got a PC on the latest Windows 10 instance, and it says me (by identifying the Ethernet cable), "Unknown network, no internet access".

There's no way to access the administrative panel of the transmitter router, only to the main one. Any cmd requests like "flush dns" and other is not helping much, same with "network reset" button.

Wi-Fi works perfectly, only PC with the cord that comes from transmitter router doesn't work. The cord from the main router is fully operational, but since that room is nearly destroyed, I can only use it with my laptop.

Do you know any way to synchronise both routers? Because all my efforts in finding the proper guide or any related information are falling apart. It's like to one have ever encountered the situation like that. If you need any additional information, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may not be able to use that Ethernet cord. If I am not mistaken, my understanding is that routers operating in a mode that extends Wifi typically either disable their Ethernet ports or use them exclusively for communication with the primary router. Your best bet would likely be to (temporarily) use Wifi on the main PC, just like the laptop.

Comment: Yeah the point is that I can't connect my PC via Wi-Fi too, because it sees 2 networks: one is from the main router, and another network comes from amplificator router. I never set any password to the second router, but it requests to write something - so, there's literally nothing to write to connect (even by leaving it blank and hit the Enter). And another network is just doesn't connect, even if I've written the password correctly and added the MAC address filter in administrative panel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here as I'm not certain of your layout of the specs of your RTRs. I've had this before with 2 standard home retail SOHO routers.

By default from factory both routers are set to DHCP server mode. **You can only ever have one DHCP server on your network**. If you have 2 DHCP servers on the network they conflict with each other and fight to setup ip  connections, you have to disable one.

I'm not sure of details of your RTR specs but for me a rough overview of my fix was to have one RTR acting as:

- internet gateway, set NAT to on, acts as a RTR
- DHCP server on.

The other RTR attached to it set to something along the lines of:

- BRIDGE MODE acting like a switch
- DHCP server off or in DHCP relay mode.

This is a rough idea, your RTR should have some similar features, but the key takeaway here is **only one RTR/DHCP server on, is ever allowed on your network** to allow your devices to connect with an ip.

NOTE:
also if you can't get to your transmitted router because it is stuck in DHCP server mode and conflicting with your other RTR you need to disconnect it from your other router so it's isolated to it's own network. Then connect in directly via LAN cable of wifi to it's web admin 192.168.0.1 admin:pwd or such to make changes before connecting it up to your other RTR.